# URL rewrite keeping old url with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I published a new version of a website and I need to create some redirection rules to keep some old urls.

What I would like to do is redirect the old address /IThomepage to the new one `/Default.aspx?lang=1` keeping IThomepage in the address bar; also, when a user type `/Default.aspx?lang=1` in the address bar I need to change the url in `/IThomepage` (folder that doesn't exist anymore) but load the new content `/Default.aspx?lang=1`

**I've tried**

```
RewriteRule ^IThomepage /default.aspx?lang=1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=1[NC]

RewriteRule ^Default\.aspx$ /IThomepage? [NC,L]
```

**and**

```
RewriteRule ^IThomepage /default.aspx?lang=1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=1[NC]

RewriteRule ^Default\.aspx$ /IThomepage? [P,NC,L]
```

**and**

```
RewriteRule ^IThomepage /default.aspx?lang=1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=1[NC]

RewriteRule ^Default\.aspx$ /IThomepage? [QSA,NC,L]
```

but I didn't have any luck; the 301 works but the address in the bar changes and the other rule returns me a 404 error as the directory doesn't exists

Hope this is clear ...

Any help?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution. This worked for me

```
RewriteRule ^IThomepage /default.aspx?lang=1 [NC, L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^IThomepage /default.aspx?lang=1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/default\.aspx [NC]
RewriteRule ^default\.aspx$ /IThomepage? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work .. I get the following error message: 'redirected you too many times' - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: Do you have any other Rewrite rules in your .htaccess or .conf files?